# How can I make my app appear under AppStore link in safari search on mobile devices?

Tags: ios, search, safari, promotions

My question may seem trivial for some of you but I'm kinda new to app promotion.

I would like to enable the appearance of my app in a safari search on mobile devices as you can see in the image bellow.
How can I make my app appear as the "Numbers" app appears in this search? (With a link to the App Store and a specific App Store container)

[image]

I've been looking around and I cannot seems to understand what procedure I should undertake to realise this.
Is this a feature of the `Core Spotlight Search` or `NSUserActivity` of apple ?

Is it an option to activate in Itunes connect ?

I thank you in advance for any information or tips you could provide for this matter or what tip of search I missed to unblock myself .

Best regards,

Martin

Comment: Does [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html) help?

Comment: Thank you for your answer I'll keep you posted on my findings based on the link you gave me.

Answer (score 1):

First of all thanks to you. I was previously thinking like it's a built in iOS feature, which will automatically do these stuffs. But I was wrong, I just did a research on this and found that there is a thing called **Universal Link**, by using that you can achieve the mentioned behaviour.

> When you support universal links, iOS users can tap a link to your
>   website and get seamlessly redirected to your installed app without
>   going through Safari. If your app isn’t installed, tapping a link to
>   your website opens your website in Safari.
>
> Universal links give you several key benefits that you don’t get when
>   you use custom URL schemes. Specifically, universal links are:
>
> - **Unique.** Unlike custom URL schemes, universal links can’t be claimed by
>     other apps, because they use standard HTTP or HTTPS links to your
>     website.
> - **Secure.** When users install your app, iOS checks a file that
>     you’ve uploaded to your web server to make sure that your website
>     allows your app to open URLs on its behalf. Only you can create and
>     upload this file, so the association of your website with your app is
>     secure.
> - **Flexible.** Universal links work even when your app is not
>     installed. When your app isn’t installed, tapping a link to your
>     website opens the content in Safari, as users expect.
> - **Simple.** One URL
>     works for both your website and your app.
> - **Private.** Other apps can
>     communicate with your app without needing to know whether your app is
>     installed.

You can read more about **Universal Links** in this documentation: [Support Universal Links](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016308-CH12-SW1)

Comment: Thank you for your time and answer. I'll dig in this direction for now.